# Behaviour of 'sort' in Clojure

Tags: sorting, clojure

As described in sort [documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sort) it's supposed to return a sorted sequence of the items in collection.

Why it properly sorts [3 1 2 4] but is unable to sort [2010 2014 2018] in ascending order?

```
$ lein repl
nREPL server started on port 62414 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:62414
REPL-y 0.3.7, nREPL 0.2.12
Clojure 1.8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_111-b14
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e

user=> (sort [2010 1014 2018])
(1014 2010 2018)
user=> (sort [3 1 2 4])
(1 2 3 4)
```

**UPDATE**: it was a typo (1014 instead of 2014) as was pointed in answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo:

```
(sort [2010 2014 2018])
```

`2014` instead of `1014`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept the answer as soon as stackoverflow allows me to do this (it has 5 minute requirement).